# How to import AndroidX correctly so it can be used in XML with autocompletion?

Tags: android, xml, autocomplete, androidx

I tried to use this preference layout

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory
        app:key="display"
        app:title="Display">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="notifications"
        app:title="Enable message notifications"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <Preference
        app:key="feedback"
        app:title="Send feedback"
        app:summary="Report technical issues or suggest new features"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

but the closing PreferenceCategory and PreferenceScreen are striked through in editor and it says android.pref... is deprecated!

When i specify complete path with androidx... the errors go away, but i want to use them without having to specify the full path...

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-rc01'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

**UPDATE**:
Deleting .idea folder and doing a "invaldidate cache & restart" did not solve it...